# How to Interpret SFDC Email Log

Tags: email

This is the first time I'm using this feature hence can someone help me to interpret SFDC email log.. The issue I'm troubleshooting here is whether the user received the case created notification email or not

Email log says,

```
10/16/2013  8:29:43 AM R    yyy@zzz.com     somesalesforceemailid
10/16/2013  8:29:46 AM D    yyy@zzz.com somesalesforceemailid
```

the confusion here is the Reception (R) mail event is recorded earlier than Delivery (D) mail event. how this is possible ?

Besides, it is possible to get the full email message ?

Answer (score 2):

From the this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_logs_format.htm&language=en_US) it looks like `R` stands for the time the server received the mail and the `D` stands for the delivery of the mail from the server to the recipient. So the data in the email logs make sense i.e., the server received the mail at 8:29:43 and delivered the mail at 8:29:46

As far as the body of the email goes, I dont think you can retrieve it.

Comment: in the case of Reception (R) event what is the path ? I mean Case created SFDC -> Outbound Email for customersupport to case owner -> SFDC mail server -> recipient mail serve -> recipient inbox ?

Comment: D usually means that the recipient server acknowledged the email, however, that doesn't guarantee that the final recipient actually received the email in their inbox.